# Loop through each WS in each open WB and unprotect

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I need to complete a task which involves collating data from a large amount of workbooks, I have put them all in the same folder and are all *xlsm files.
I already have a macro to grab the data from each sheet and enter it all onto a master sheet as I have done this before.

How ever each sheet is now password protected to restrict users, i need to:

-Open each workbook
-loop through each sheet and unlock it with the password ("Which I have")

At the moment the below code opens each workbook and unlocks the one that is currently active but doesn't loop through each open workbook.

```
Sub OpenFiles()
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pwd As String

pwd = "password"

'_______Opens every excel file in folder_______

MyFolder = "Test"

MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.xlsm")
Do While MyFile <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile
MyFile = Dir
Loop

For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    For Each ws In Worksheets
      ws.Unprotect Password:=pwd
    Next ws
Next wb

End Sub
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub tmpSO()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        ws.Unprotect "Which I have"
    Next ws
Next wb

End Sub
```

Comment: That seems to work perfectly on my test folder, thank you